# Strip out create-react-app dev server with craco

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, craco

I'm building a mono-repo project that uses [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) to generate the front-end and serves the statically built files with a node server.

In order to create a development `watch` script that watches both backend and front-end code for changes, we've opted for [cra-build-watch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cra-build-watch), which has worked okay. The problem is, I'd like to do more tweaking of the create-react-app config without ejecting, preferably using [craco](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco). It seems possible achieve the same results that cra-build-watch does by using craco, which would then allow further customization of the resulting webpack config.

How do I strip out the dev server from create-react-app using craco, such that the `/src` and `/static` files are watched and outputted in the `/build` directory, but not the fully optimized versions? (So it's quick)